# HTML url passing multiple parameters

Tags: html, url, routes

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters with an url. I have checked out almost every topic about it, but can't seem to find an answer. I have tried different ways, but it still doesn't work.

It is only  sending the first parameter.

If I start with post_id - I can't get comment_id

If I start with comment_id - I can' get post_id

My idea of url:

```
http://localhost/index.php?post_id=3&comment_id=6
```

OR

```
http://localhost/index.php?post_id=3&amp;comment_id=6
```

I try to use it later like this:

```
else if(isset($_GET['post_id']) & isset($_GET['comment_id'])){
        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        $comment_id = $_GET['comment_id'];
        $user_id = $this->UserModel->getUser();
        $BlogPost = $this->BlogModel->getBlogPost($post_id);
        $BlogComments = $this->BlogModel->getBlogCommentList($post_id);
        $BlogComments = $this->BlogModel->deleteBlogComment($comment_id,$user_id);
        include 'views/ViewBlogPost.php';
}
```

Comment: Your first URL is correct: `http://localhost/index.php?post_id=3&comment_id=6`. It looks like you might be using PHP-- I have a feeling there is something incorrect in the code that's receiving the query. Also, check this out, I find this helpful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below URL Structure is perfactly true

```
http://localhost/index.php?post_id=3&comment_id=6
```

Logic to Pass data Through URL in your script is called as QueryString Which you can build in below way
NAME=VALUE - this is called Name Value Pair , you can Pass Multiple Name Value pair by appending with '&' only
e.g.

```
 http://localhost/index.php?name_1=value_1&name_2=value_2
```

on server side you will retrive them by using GLOBAL $_GET  e.g print_r($_GET); to view all the passed data.

individually you can access them by using 
     echo $_GET['name_1']; echo $_GET['name_2'];

Also i suggest you to check your GPSC setting in your php.ini to define the priorities between your Super Globals.